# Java Rest JSON Array Input

Tags: java, json, rest

I need a REST method that shall both handle single instance of a input object and a array of it. Request content is application\json.
HTTP Request content shall be like:

`{"param":"value"}`  for single input

or

`[{"param":"value1"}, {"param":"value2"},{"param":"value3"}]` for array input.

My Input class shall be like:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Input {
    @XmlElement(name="param")
   private String value;
}
```

I wrote two REST methods as follows:

```
@Path("test")
public class MyResource {

    //Method that shall handle array input
    @Post
    public Response method(Input[] inputs) {
       //TODO
       return Response.ok().build();
    }

    //Method that shall handle single input
    @Post
    public Response method(Input input) {
       //TODO
       return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

But this solution does not work. I use JBOSS RestEasy as JAX-RS provider.
Can someone offer a solution for this case?

Comment: the 2 methods must at least be annotated with @POST.

Answer (score 0):

Try with annotations :

```
//Method that shall handle array input
@Path("method")
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
   public Response method(Input[] inputs) {
   //TODO
   return Response.ok().build();
}

//Method that shall handle single input
@Path("method2")
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response method2(Input input) {
   //TODO
   return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand, OP wants the same URL to accept both JSON array and JSON object. Here you'd have two different paths.